# Table with 4 columns (all width of screen) and 2 rows applying flip effect jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, uitableview

I am working on a effect using jquery to flip cards, currently I have:

[image]

But I would like to create a kind of matrix 4columns and 2 rows like this:

[image]

The issue here is That I do not know how to make this matrix occupy all width of screen (any type of width in any screen) so I made the `width = 100%` in a table lay-out:

```
#wrapper {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;    
    width:100%;
}
#wrapper div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

to occupy all width.

But how can I assure the images are like the wanted image occupaying all width? 
Also I do not know how to make a second row...?

Could you please help me getting the desired output?
Here is what I have so far  [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2UTg8/),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `width:25%` on the `.card-container`

[See on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fUsPh/)

Here are the changed I made:

```
section.card-container{
    float: left;
    margin:0;
    width:25%;
}

/*#wrapper {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;    
    width:100%;
}
#wrapper div {
    display: table-cell;
}*/
```

Adding another row is as simple as duplicating the elements

[See on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fUsPh/1/)